# read multiple lines from one TSV file and based on column append data with comma

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, text-parsing, csv

How do we parse data based on column index from TSV file?
Once we read data from file then we must have to check column 0 line 1 data with column 0 line 2 data and if it's matching then get column 1 line 1 data and need to append all the matching entries in column 1 line 1.

For example,
SystemType.tsv file

```
Actrius  1990s drama films 
Actrius  Catalan language films 
Actrius  Spanish films 
Actrius  Barcelona in fiction 
Actrius  Films directed by Ventura Pons 
Actrius  1996 films 
An_American_in_Paris     Compositions by George Gershwin 
An_American_in_Paris     Symphonic poems 
An_American_in_Paris     Grammy Hall of Fame Award recipients
```

In column 0 line 1 "Actrius" is there so we need to compare all the lines in column 0 and placed matched entries column 1 value with comma separated form as below.

Output:

```
Actrius   1990s drama flims,Cataln language flims,Spanish flims,Barcelona in fiction,Films directed by Ventura Pons,1996 films
An_American_in_Paris    Compositions by George Gershwin,Symphonic poems,Grammy Hall of Fame Award recipients
```

I have tried this one but doesn't work for me.

```
def finalextract():
    lines_seen = set()
    outfile = open("Output.txt","w+")
    infile = open("SystemType.tsv","r+")
    for line in infile:
        if line[0] == lines_seen[0]:
            string = line[1]+','+lines_seen[1]
            outfile.write(string)
            lines_seen.add(string)
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with (Python 3, but I think the only difference should be my print function. You can `from __future__ import print_function` if you want to use it to write to the output file):

```
import collections

# I used variable "input" to hold the string from your example .tsv contents;
# you'd really want to read it in from a file.

D = collections.OrderedDict()
for line in input.splitlines():
    key, value = line.split('\t')
    if key not in D:
        D[key] = []
    D[key].append(value.strip())

for key, values in D.items():
    print(key, ','.join(values), sep='\t')
```

My output is:

```
Actrius 1990s drama films,Catalan language films,Spanish films,Barcelona in fiction,Films directed by Ventura Pons,1996 films
An_American_in_Paris    Compositions by George Gershwin,Symphonic poems,Grammy Hall of Fame Award recipients
```